# Adding a WMS to XMap 8

Tags: wms, global-mapper

I'm having trouble adding a WMS to XMap 8, and I'm curious if it can be done at all.

I've been using Global Mapper for geologic research for quite a while, which has the ability to download data from inside the program, from a number of sources (World Imagery is of particular use to me, as well as NE US 10m DEM and NE US Topo).

The company I work for now uses XMap 8, which seems to be a little more robust than Global Mapper, at the cost of the easy data download (or so it seems). I'm in the process of learning Xmap, which must be used due to license restrictions.

Essentially, I need to be able to zoom to a location in XMap, download a topo map, imagery, and elevation and work with the data (the tools are able to do everything I need at this point, but getting the data is a bit troublesome).

If there's a simple workaround or quick way of plopping the maps into XMap, I would be more than happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is still struggling with getting data from WMS services... WMS map tiles can be downloaded for further off-line use using [WMS Downloader](http://geotrix.eu/). You can **download georeferenced map tiles** in any projection, scale and format (e.g. tif, jpeg, png), which can be then used in any application that consumes georeferenced images (I suppose XMap does).

The tool is available as the ArcGIS Add-In as well as a standalone Windows app. Disclaimer: I'm one of the coauthors of this tool and this is a licensed product. Feel free to check the trial version and video tutorials on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtjtGxELdYVqWo6U-d7n25A/videos).